# Obtaining datetime value from database and getting its hour int

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, datetime

I am new to Ruby/Ruby on Rails and I was wondering if it is possible to get a `datetime` entry `:starts_at` from my `events` table in my database and obtain from it an integer representing just the hour value?

The datetime '`:starts_at`'has the layout:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
e.g. 2016-01-03 11:05:00
```

what I would want is just the "11" representing the hour, so I can set it as variable "`start_hour`".

I am not sure how to obtain my `:starts_at` value from the database in the first place, but here is some attempt at code showing what I mean.

Doing:

```
events.each do |event|
    start_time = event(:starts_at.hour) #is this how to obtain :starts_at?
end
```

would return "11:00" instead of "11", how would I narrow it down to just "11"? And if the time was "08:00" it should be "8"?

Comment: `event.starts_at` will give you the db value. Then you can use strftime to get the desired format

Comment: I tried that but my IDE underlines starts_at saying "can't find starts_at"

Comment: IDEs warnings can be wrong while coding ruby. Run a test or run your app to check if it works

Comment: but it doesn't do that for any other field, just starts_at? ok I will run it

Answer (score 2):

`event.starts_at` is the DateTime object. Use [Time#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) to get the desired format. eg:

```
event.starts_at.strftime("%H")
```

Comment: event.starts_at does not return a DateTime object. Verify with event.starts_at.class in console.

Answer (score 1):

event.starts_at returns an object of class [ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html)
It provides an 'hour' reader:

```
event.starts_at.hour
```

But please consider that starts_at also could be nil. So if you can't ensure presence of starts_at, you better go with something like:

```
event.starts_at && event.starts_at.hour
```